# Prevent onclick event in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onclick

I can not seem to get IE8 to prevent the onclick function from executing.  Tried numerous code variations.  Any help would be appreciated.  As it stands now when I click on the link I get the alert popup which should not be happening.

```
 <p><a href="#" onclick="openMoreProductVideos('Video title','videocode','false');return false;"><span class="txt">View all videos</span></a></p>

function openMoreProductVideos(title,productCode,fastprevoew) 
{  
  alert ("openMoreProductVideos - should not see this!");
}

$('a[onclick^=openMoreProductVideos]').click(function (event) {
   if (event.stopPropagation){
         event.stopPropagation();
   }
   else if(window.event){
      window.event.cancelBubble=true;       
   }       
    return false;
});
```

Comment: what does `alert(event.stopPropagation);` show? And why do you need two event handlers in your code?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery/) will help and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute/) too :)

Answer (score 1):

just try this..removing the other conditions..

```
$('a[onclick^=openMoreProductVideos]').click(function (event) {

   event.preventDefault();      //will prevent the event from occuring


});
```

check the jsfiddle ..[jsfiddle.net/kabichill/qu7kP](http://jsfiddle.net/kabichill/qu7kP)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, `stopPropagation()` and `cancelBubble` are used to stop the event from going further up the chain of listeners, but will still execute the current listener.  Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: yes and that does not work either.  I think what needs to happen is the eventhandler needs to be removed first but not sure how to get that working for IE8.  for example, the following code works for ff and chrome but not for IE.

    $('a[onClick^=openMoreProductVideos]').each(function (e) {
    this.onclick = undefined;
 });

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me in IE8+ & FF

```
function stopEvent(e) {    
    if (!e) e = window.event;

    if (e.cancelBubble != null) e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); //e.stopPropagation works in Firefox.
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    if (e.returnValue != null) e.returnValue = false; // http://blog.patricktresp.de/2012/02/
    return false;
}
```

**IMP :** FYI, I got stuck with if(e.cancelBubble) for IE, it has to be if(e.cancelbubble != null)