# Return false with onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, onclick

I have this code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">a</li>   
    <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">b</li>
    <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">c</li>
</ul>
```

I want to prevent the default action `alert()` when click in `<li>` with text "a", and I use this code:

```
$(document).on('click','.foo', function(){
    if ($(this).text()=='a')
        return false;
});
```

But this doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/Trk6W/10/

Is there a solution **only modifying the javascript**?

Updated: I dont wanna remove the attribute `onclick` because the values of `li` can change

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, use a class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery

Comment: The `onclick` attribute code is running before the jQuery click handler. You can't stop something that has already happened.

Comment: I dont wanna remove the onclick attribute becasue the values of the `<li>` can change. BTW, i updated the answer with 'class' instead 'id'

Comment: @MichaelAguilar Then don't use the `onclick` attribute - store data associated with the element in `data-*` attributes. For example `<li class="foo" data-something="whatever">a</li>`. You can then get the stored value with `$(element).attr("data-something")` or `$(element).data("something")`. Don't try and mix basic and jQuery event handling

Comment: @Ian the onclick attribute is generated by .NET, I wanna know if there's a simple way to resolve this issue

Comment: @MichaelAguilar Ahh I see. Well I can't imagine it doing it *automatically* (especially for an `alert`), so you really can't modify it happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the jQuery code runs after the onclick attribute. So there is no way to make it work with the way you currently have it set up. The solution would be to look for the onclick elements and move it to another event, and have the onclick that you add dynamically trigger than event.

```
$(".foo").each( function() {
   this._onclick = this.onclick;
   this.onclick = null;
});


$(document).on('click','.foo', function(){
    if ($(this).text()!=='a') {
        this._onclick.apply(this,arguments);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LZMM/1/)

The problem with this method is, if the content is added dynamically, you would have to call the code that converts the click.

Comment: a very good answer and solution. I think is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Besides the unique id caveat, just remove the `onclick` attr:

**Markup:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">a</li>   
  <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">b</li>
  <li class="foo" onclick="alert('Hello')">c</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.foo').map(function(){ 
  if($(this).text() == 'a')
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick')
});
```

Comment: BUT the OP wants it to fire!

Comment: But the OP said `I want to prevent the default action alert()`

Comment: @epascarello now I removed it just for the desired element. If user wants to retain a copy of original event, he may do like in the solution you proposed.

Answer (score -1):

You could set a `class` for your duplicated elements, and use the following snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li class="foo">a</li>
    <li class="foo">b</li>
    <li class="foo">c</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $('.foo').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).text() === 'a'){
            return false;
        }
        // Whatever you want here.
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You removed the onclick events that are on it and jQuery runs after the onclick that is on the element so your solution fails.