# Button disable/enable onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 buttons like this :

```
$body .= '<a href="#" onclick="check();" id="check">Check </i></a>';
$body .= '<a  href="#" onclick="continue();" id="cont">Continue </a>';
```

I want that the Continue button is disable if the user don't click on the Check button.

I have this :

```
    $('#cont').click(function(){return false; });
$('#check').click(function() {
    $('#cont').unbind('click');
});
```

But when I click on the Continue button (before click on the check) The href don't work it's good but the onclick work ! How I can disable the onclick with the href. Thank you

Comment: jQuery doesn't disable the inline onclick attribute, you should be using proper event handlers that can be attached and removed with on() and off().

Comment: I think you want something like... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this

```
$body .= '<a href="#" onclick="check();" id="check">Check</a>';
$body .= '<a  href="#" onclick="continue();" id="cont" disabled>Continue </a>';
```

and jquery code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[name^="check"]').change(function() {   
        if( $('#cont').prop('disabled'))
         $('#cont').prop('disabled',false);
        else
            $('#cont').prop('disabled',true);
    });    

});
```

you can use this link http://jsfiddle.net/DC3EH/101/

Comment: It isn't work for me ? can you give me a JSFiddle ? Thank you

Comment: i used jquery 1.8,you can directly use click ,live  instead of on .go throught the docs. if you find the answer mark as answer and upvote.. you can directly paste your code in jsfiddle and test it

Comment: use this jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/DC3EH/101/  and this is even better to u http://jsfiddle.net/DC3EH/103/, if its works mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery's` [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [off](http://api.jquery.com/off/). Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYbCw/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove onclick attribute from both buttons and use below code, if works

Disable the continue button initially

```
$body .= '<a href="#" id="check">Check</a>';
$body .= '<a  href="#" id="cont" disabled="disabled">Continue </a>';

$('#check').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#cont').prop({disabled:false});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="check();" id="check">Check </i></a>
<a href="#" onclick="continueX();" id="cont">Continue </a>
```

My JS:

```
function check(){
    //console.log('Check >>>');
    //Whatever you run...
}

function continueX(){
    //console.log('continue >>>');
    //Whatever you run...
}

$('#cont').each(function(){
    //block clicking:
    $(this).click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); return false});

    //Store its current inline onclick property;
    $(this).data('onclick', this.onclick);

    //add a class to identify itself:
    $(this).addClass('disabled');

    //Re-define it:
    this.onclick = function(event) {
        //Restrict click if it has disabled class:
        if( $(this).hasClass('disabled') ){
            return false;
        };

        //otherwise, call inline onclick:
        $(this).data('onclick').call(this, event || window.event);
    };
});

$('#check').click(function(){
    //now allow click:
    $('#cont').unbind('click').removeClass('disabled');
});
```