# onbind or remove onclick attr failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

The alert doesn't get fire because the openClose() function is missing and it throw an error.

```
<div class="spoilertop" onclick="openClose('cbd6c32c3118dbbdc3fbdc37e0805292')">
```

How I can I unbind or better remove the onclick tag?

```
$('.spoilertop').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');

    alert('f');
})
```

I tried `$(this).attr('onclick','').unbind('click');` and e.preventDefault() but doesn't work.

Comment: can't really understand this : I want to add a click event to a class but the tag is from somewhere else

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery

Answer (score 2):

Your code works - the `onclick` attribute is removed *after* the first click fires. However, `onclick` fires before the `click` in jQuery so `openClose` will always fire the first time, see [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/yg5790uw/). You'll see that the `foo` alert only shows for the first click.

To avoid this you either need to remove that attribute from the element on load, or better yet, remove it from the HTML completely.

To remove it from the `.spoliertop` elements on load, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.spoilertop').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: I can't remove the attr because it's from somewhere else.. or you are saying i remove it before the click event?

Comment: I've added example code to show how to remove it on load of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/yg5790uw/1/

Comment: I've having problem to remove it coz I'm using ajax call then bind the result to the dom. I put in .finally() still couldn't get the onclick removed.

Comment: I'd suggest you open a new question detailing the full process you go through, including JSON calls etc. I'd say this question has been covered now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.spoilertop').click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
    alert('Off');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tegos/h414hkhs/)