# Stop onclick method running with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button similar to below

```
<button id="uniqueId" onclick="runMethod(this)">Submit</button>
```

What I'm trying to do is stop the runMethod from running, until after I've done a check of my own. I've tried using the `stopImmediatePropagation` function, but this doesn't seem to have worked. Here's my jQuery:

```
$j(document).on('click', '#uniqueId', function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if(condition == true) {
        // continue...
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Note: `runMethod` basically validates the form, then triggers a submit.

Comment: Try `$j(document)` to `$(document)`?

Comment: Why do you have `onclick="runMethod"` and click handler?

Comment: I'm using noConflict and binding to $j

Comment: @Karl Oh got it, thought something was a bit off..

Comment: `event.stopImmediatePropagation` works totally different.. Make use of `callback functions` here...

Comment: I have no control of the `runMethod` function, as this is part of the software I am using. So I need to build around it, I cannot modify it, or remove the onclick method.

Comment: To stop current, you have to use `event.preventDefault()` and to stop bubbling `event.stopImmediatePropogation()`

Comment: @Rajesh, I have tried both, preventDefault and stopImmediatePropogation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent onclick action with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756425/prevent-onclick-action-with-jquery)

Comment: Might be issue with noConflict() declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do, especially in the way that you want to do it, requires a some sort of workaround that will always be a bit fiddly. It is a better idea to change the way the button behaves (e.g. handle the whole of the click event on the inside of the jQuery `click()` function or something along those lines). However I have found sort of a solution for your problem, based on the assumption that your user will first hover over the button. I am sure you can extend that functionality to the keyboard's `Tab` event, but maybe it will not work perfectly for mobile devices' touch input. So, bear in mind the following solution is a semi-complete workaround for your problem:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var methodToRun = "runMethod(this)";    // Store the value of the onclick attribute of your button.
    var condition = false;                  // Suppose it is enabled at first.
    $('#uniqueId').attr('onclick',null);
    $('#uniqueId').hover(function(){
        // Check your stuff here
        condition = !condition;     // This will change to both true and false as your hover in and out of the button.
        console.log(condition);     // Log the condition's value.
        if(condition == true){      
            $('#uniqueId').attr('onclick',methodToRun); // Enable the button's event before the click.
        }
    },
    function(){     
        console.log('inactive');    // When you stop hovering over the button, it will log this.
        $('#uniqueId').attr('onclick',null);    // Disable the on click event.
    });
});
```

What this does is it uses the `hover` event to trigger your checking logic and when the user finally clicks on the button, the button is enabled if the logic was correct, otherwise it does not do anything. Try it live on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6atLn55j/4/).

**P.S.:** Convert `$` to `$j` as necessary to adapt this.

**P.S.2:** Use the Javascript console to check how the fiddle works as it will not change anything on the page by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `submit` event, just make :

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

and it works. Don't bind the button click, only the submit form. By this way, you prevent to submit the form and the button needs to be type button:

```
 <button type="button" .....>Submit</button>
```

Assuming there's a form that is submitted when button is clicked.

Comment: Just tried this, but had no luck. The button does have the correct type, but the onclick is still fired

Comment: But don't you remove the onclick attribute in button?

Comment: No, I'm unable to remove the onclick as this is part of the software I am using and it's used in other places.

Comment: So the easiest solution is remove the onclick attribute dinamically. `$(document).ready(function() { $('#uniqueId').removeAttr('onclick'); })` And then write the submit event with the `preventDefault()` method, and then call manually to `runMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
event.cancelBubble();
```

Hence your code becomes:

```
$j(document).on('click', '#uniqueId', function(event) {
    // Don't propogate the event to the document


 if (event.stopPropagation) {
      event.stopPropagation();   // W3C model
  } else {
      event.cancelBubble = true; // IE model
  }



    if(condition == true) {
        // continue...
    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is mostly correct but you need to remove J:

```
$(document).on('click', '#uniqueId', function(event) {...
```

You also need to remove the onClick event from the inline code - there's no need to have it there when you're assigning it via jQuery.

```
<button id="uniqueId">Submit</button>
```

Comment: This is incorrect, I am using noConflict and binding to $j

Comment: To avoid j-query from conflicting with other libraries No-Conflict Mode `$j` is used. New thing for me....